# Smoke isn't rendering in cycles 2.92

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I was trying to make a smoke sim but noticed after baking that the smoke doesn't render, the sim shows up in wireframe view. Any help?

[https://pasteall.org/blend/0cc1f3837ff24ccaa43e8c4e6ee1c080](.blend file)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

give this material setup to your domain:

[image]