# Smoke Simulation in Blender 2.92

Tags: smoke-simulation

**Disclaimer**: I'm pretty new to blender, most things I say are mostly based on observations.

So I was trying to make a Smoke + Fire simulation in Blender 2.92. The goal is to have a (UV-)Sphere emit smoke and fire in the shape of a cone. After researching, I followed the official [docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/physics/smoke/index.html) and added some nodes based on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219358/smoke-isnt-rendering-in-cycles-2-92). I checked if the domain is actually a domain object and if the flow is actually a flow object and both of them are.

The problem I'm facing is that the smoke and the fire go in the wrong direction (at least from what I can observe). Rotating either cone or ball does nothing, the smoke just moves on an almost two-dimensional plane.

Please download my [.blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Jyz6ek4M/) since I can't upload images yet because I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

i worked with your file and i very easy because The smoke domain can only be a cube or a Cuboid.thats your are not able to get a desired result.Your have to make your domain as cube and cone to effect in the physics tab.I also made some changes to your file my adding noise to our object (sphere) if you don't want it you can change it.Also make sure that you make change in object flow type(sphere) to inflow.

Read this post below....
[Why isn't smoke flowing with the shape of the domain?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51964/why-isnt-smoke-flowing-with-the-shape-of-the-domain)

your blend file
[image]